# Extracting SharePoint data on daily basis

Tags: powershell, csv, export, sharepoint, string

I want to export my SharePoint document library data on daily basis and csv file need to be save as naming convention as Dataname_yyyyMMdd. As per my below script, it need to export data from the sharepoint library into one CSV file as name Data_yyyyMMdd. Then it need to imports the data from Data_yyyyMMdd and adds "header" to the file and then export to new final output CSV as name "DataName_yyyyMMdd".

While running the script i am getting only one file as Data_yyyyMMdd. The data from file was not importing to final csv file and its not generating the final output file DataName_yyyyMMdd. Please correct me if doing wrong in script. Please share me correct script.

### Powershell script

$web = get-spweb $siteUrl
$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq $listTitle}
$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.ViewFields = ""
$query.RowLimit=5000

do

$ListName1 = "Data"
$ExportFolder1 = “C:\Users\”
$ExportName1 = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath1 = $ExportFolder1 + $ListName1 + $ExportName1 + “.csv”
$ListName = "Dataname_"
$ExportFolder = “C:\Users\csv\”
$ExportName = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath = $ExportFolder + $ListName + $ExportName + “.csv”
{
$caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query)
$query.ListItemCollectionPosition=$caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
$listItemsTotal = $caseLibItems.Count
$x = 0
for($x=0;$x -lt $listItemsTotal; $x++)
{
    $Description = $caseLibItems[$x]["DocumentSetDescription"]
    $str = ""
    if('$Description' -ne $null)
    {
        $Description = $Description -replace "`n"," " -replace "`r"," "
        $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString() + '}' + $Description
    }
    else
    {
        $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()
    }

Write-Output $str | Out-File $ExportPath1 -Append
}

} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

Import-csv $ExportPath1 -delimiter "}" -Header "Number", "Description"  | export-csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Exiting"

Answer (score 0):

Export SharePoint list data to CSV

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

## Get the Web

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "sitename"

## Get the Target List

$list = $web.Lists["Monthly Schedule Log"]

## Array to Hold Result - PSObjects

$ListItemCollection = @()

#Get All List items where Status is "In Progress"
 $list.Items |  Where-Object { $*["Status"] -eq "In Progress"} | foreach {
 $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $*["Title"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Department" -value $*["Department"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Status" -value $*["Status"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Priority" -value $_["Priority"]

#Add the object with property to an Array
 $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
 #Export the result Array to CSV file
 $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\List.txt" -NoTypeInformation

## Dispose the web Object

$web.Dispose()

All fields Export using PowerShell

## Variables

$SiteUrl="site"
$OutPutFile = "location"

## Get Web and User Information List

$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$UserInfoList = $Web.SiteUserInfoList
Write-host "Total Number of Items Found:"$UserInfoList.Itemcount

## Array to Hold Result - PSObjects

$ListItemCollection = @()

#Get All List items where Status is "In Progress"
 $UserInfoList.Items | foreach {
 write-host "Processing Item ID:"$_["ID"]

$ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
   #Get Each field
   foreach($Field in $*.Fields)
    {
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $Field.InternalName -value $*[$Field.InternalName]
    }
    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem

}

## Export the result Array to CSV file

$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $OutPutFile -NoTypeInformation
Write-host "User Information List Exported to $($OutputFile) for site $($SiteURL)"

$web.Dispose()